# Using component state via fragments passed through args in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, storybook

I'm defining fragments in my stories file and passing them into my component with the args. My problem is that, being defined outside of the component, they can't see my useState hooks. How can I access the component state via fragments defined outside the component?

In the stories file...

```
const fragment1 = (props) => <>
  fragment1
</>

const fragment2 = (props) => <>
  fragment2
</>

...

Default.args = {
  fragments: [
    fragment1,
    fragment2
  ]
}
```

Comment: You may use either Redux or React Context

Comment: Please share some code, so we can better understand what you did and where you want to go.

Comment: How would I do this with Context?